# Inserting content from multiple textareas at once

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have two divs each containing their own tinymce editor instance and hidden input value:

```
    <form method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-12 fullWidth" id="full">
        <input type="hidden" name="fullWidth" value="">
        <div class="fullContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="panel" value="1">
              <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea3" name="fullText">Some Text Here</textarea><!--I want to save this content along with panel_type_id = 1-->
              <input type="submit" value="Save Content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 halfWidth" id="half">
        <input type="hidden" name="halfWidth" value="">
        <div class="halfContent" style="background-color: white; height: 100%;">
                <input type="hidden" name="panel" value="2">
              <textarea class="original" id="mytextarea4" name="halfText">Some Text There</textarea><!--I want to save this content along with panel_type_id = 2-->
              <input type="submit" value="Save Content">

        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

As you see, the fullwidth div should have a 'panel' value of '1' and the halfwidth div should have a 'panel' value of '2'. Once text is entered and the user hits save, there is a small form where they enter the title of the page, and it also captures the 'pageType' from the 'value' in the URL. This works fine but at form submission I also want to inherit the content and 'panel' value of each above DIV's textarea. Here's the form but I don't know how to handle multiple panel types and content.

```
<form action="addPage.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="pageType" value="<?php echo $value;?>">//This comes from the url value
<input type="hidden" name="panel" value="">
<input class="form-control" id="addTitle" name="addTitle"><!--Page Title-->
<input type="submit" name="Save Page">
```

The problem is, when I now call my addPage.php script to insert the records, I don't know how to pass the values correctly so that I add one page record (the $value for page_type_id and the Title) but then insert 2 content and panel records for the text areas.

Here's my expected insert in the case of the above code:

```
pages

ID | Title    | page_type_id
1  | TitleNew | 1     /*this comes from $value*/

content

ID | Content
1  | Some Text Here
2  | Some Text There

panels

ID | panel_type_ID | page_id | content_id
1  |     1         |     1   |   1
2  |     2         |     1   |   2
```

This works for one insert in all 3 tables but if I can set multiple panel types to each div, how can I modify this to still insert the one page record but successfully account for multiple panel and content?

Here's the add page script

```
//This works for one record, but I think I need to add some kind of foreach or while into the insert for content and panel

//Insert Page
$title = $_POST['addTitle'];
$page_type = $_POST['pageType'];


$addpage = "
    INSERT INTO pages (title, page_type_id)
    VALUES ('$title','$page_type');
";
$mysqlConn->query($addpage)

$page_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;

foreach(//panel and content){
//Insert Content
$content = $_POST['page_content'];

$addContent = "
    INSERT INTO content(content)
    VALUES('$content');
";

$mysqlConn->query($addContent);

$cont_id = $mysqlConn->insert_id;

//Insert panel(s)
$panelID = $_POST['panelType'];
$addPanel = "
    INSERT INTO panels(panel_type_id, page_id, cont_id)
    VALUES ('$panelID', '$page_id', '$cont_id');
";
$mysqlConn->query($addPanel);

}
```

Comment: Your hidden inputs are both in the same form, with the same name. There can only be one

Comment: How would I change that though? even if I give them different names, I'm having an issue passing the values

Comment: @kerbholz What would be the better way to assign each div it's own panel type ID? And then, I still need to be able to take that ID and the content of each and submit to mysql